# Pricing the Passport option

Tags: options, stochastic-calculus, derivatives, differential-equations

Suppose underlying asset $S$
$$dS = \mu Sdt + \sigma Sd W$$
our portfolio $\pi$ consist with $q(t)$ `stock` $S$ and `cash` $\pi - qS$ at time $t,$ so we have
$$d\pi = r(\pi− qS) dt + q dS.$$
with $|q|\leq 1.$

And assume the final payment of our `passport option` is
$$V(\pi,s, T) = \max\{\pi,0\}.$$
Use the `hedge portfolio`, we can obtain the `PDE`
$$V_t + \dfrac{1}{2}\sigma^2s^2 V_{ss} + q\sigma^2s^2V_{s\pi} + \dfrac{1}{2}q^2\sigma^2s^2V_{\pi\pi} + rsV_s + r\pi V_{\pi} -rV = 0.$$

We want to choose $q(t)$ to `maximize` $V.$

One thing I confuse here, why does author only easily maximize the terms containing $q$ in the PDE? i.e
$$\max\limits_{|q|\leq 1}\ \left(q\sigma^2s^2V_{s\pi} + \dfrac{1}{2}q^2\sigma^2s^2V_{\pi\pi}\right) $$

That is the book `Paul Wilmott on Quantitative Finance` page 455
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: "[...] _why does **author** only easily maximize_ [...]": could you add a link to or specify the reference?

Comment: Sorry I do not understand your question, could you please give more about the context?

Comment: @DaneelOlivaw pls the update

Comment: @lehalle pls the update

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You maximize the terms in $q$ in the PDE because this is a consequence of the Bellman principle of optimality in dynamic programming. The intuition is that the global optimal strategy $\{q_t\}_{0 \leq t \leq T}$ is locally optimal such that (under the risk neutral measure  because the option is dynamically hedged)
$$V_t = \max_{|q_t|\leq 1}e^{-r dt}E_t\left[V_{t+dt} \right]$$ 
that is 
$$
V(\pi, S, t) = \max_{|q|\leq 1}e^{-r dt} E_t\left[V(\pi+ d\pi, S+dS, t+dt) \right]
$$
along with the stochastic dynamics (under the risk neutral measure)
$$
dS = rS dt + \sigma S dW
$$
$$
d\pi=r(\pi - qS) dt + qdS
$$
and the terminal condition $V(\pi, S, T) =\max(\pi, 0)$. In words, you start from the end and go back in time, finding the optimal strategy at each time step conditional on the state you're in.

You then apply Ito's lemma to $V(\pi+ d\pi, S+dS, t+dt)$ to obtain the author's result.